# Why laravel Query builder doesn't support joins with IN condition operator?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was trying to do something like this in Laravel:

```
DB::table('TABLE1')->join('TABLE2', 'COLUMN1', 'IN', '(1,2,3)')
```

but when I looked into Builder.php file, these are the only operators that are supported for *ON* clause:

```
public $operators = [
    '=', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '<>', '!=',
    'like', 'like binary', 'not like', 'between', 'ilike',
    '&', '|', '^', '<<', '>>',
    'rlike', 'regexp', 'not regexp',
    '~', '~*', '!~', '!~*', 'similar to',
    'not similar to', 'not ilike', '~~*', '!~~*',
];
```

Is there any reason that *IN* is not listed in *$operators*?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `whereIn` on your join clauses:

```
DB::table('table_name')->join('table_name', function($join) {
    $join->whereIn('table_name.column', ['valueA', 'valueB', 'valueC']);
}
```

**A quick tip:** Some questions are already answered on Laravel's GitHub repository: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15366

Laravel 5.3 upgrade notes contains the following information:

> The operator of the `on` clause is now checked as well and can no
>   longer contain invalid values. If you were relying on that feature
>   (e.g. `$join->on('foo', 'in', DB::raw('("bar")'))`) you should rewrite
>   the condition using the appropriate where clause:
>
> ```
>  $join->whereIn('foo', ['bar']);
> ```